# How do I handle contractions with regex word boundaries in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, cpu-word

I have a nodejs script that reads in a file and counts word frequencies. I currently feed each line into a function:

```
function getWords(line) {
    return line.match(/\b\w+\b/g);
}
```

This matches almost everything, except it misses contractions

```
getWords("I'm") -> {"I", "m"}
```

However, I cannot just include apostrophes, as I would want *matched* apostrophes to be word boundaries:

```
getWords("hey'there'") -> {"hey", "there"}
```

Is there a way capture contractions while still treating other apostrophes as word boundaries?

Comment: How can _you_ tell that `I'm` should be split but `hey'there'` should not?  Sounds like this might require a dictionary?

Comment: will "hey'there'" really appear like that, or will it have a space like "hey 'there'"?

Comment: What if the input is `"I'm Steve O'Conner's 'friend'"`? How would you know that `O'Conner's` is actually one word, not three? Or what if the matched apostrophes you mention contain a contraction with another apostrophe?

Comment: @nnnnnn my answer below seems to cover that case but it could use more testing

Comment: It will PROBABLY also have a space, but I can't really guarantee it. The script just accepts random files, be they source files, text files, html, or whatever, and counts word frequencies. I need "I'm" to be considered a single word, with html properties and code like syntax to continue to be treated with ' as a word boundary.

Comment: using just a regex, I believe you'll have to settle for `hey'there'` being considered the contraction `hey'there` if no space is provided to differentiate it. You could use a dictionary of known contractions as @Aaron Dufour alluded to. But that seems a bit much for the general use you seem to have

Comment: My question is, for the record, neither a joke nor rhetorical.  You're going to have a hard time getting the answer you want unless you provide actual criteria for making the determination. @DelightedD0D's answer is good, but it drops the apostrophe from words like "'twas" and "'ow", which are also contractions, and it's not clear whether that's important to you.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of prefacing apostrophes. The answer below is what I'm now running with in lieu of a solution that could accomodate them; could you provide an alternative that would capture `'twas`?

Answer (score 5):

The closest I believe you could get with regex would be `line.match(/(?!'.*')\b[\w']+\b/g)` but be aware that if there is no space between a word and a `'`, it will get treated as a contraction.

As Aaron Dufour mentioned, there would be no way for the regex by itself to know that `I'm` is a contraction but `hey'there` isn't.

See below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'm using this for now. Do note that it wasn't `hey'there`, it was `hey'there'`, I thought it could be determined by ' matching but your example of `O'Conner` leads me to consider double-apostrophe words that I would want matched, like `O'Hares'` and 'O'Conner's`. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped, what I meant was just that this regex will match `hey'there'` as `hey'there` due to no space being betwen `y` and the `'`

Comment: Got it. What's the screenshot from?

Comment: It's regexbuddy, http://www.regexbuddy.com/. It costs $40 but well worth it in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

You can match letters and a possible apostrophe followed by letters.

```
line.match(/[A-Za-z]+('[A-Za-z]+)?/g
```